# Neo4j not saving graph + cant run as service

Tags: neo4j

I am using ElementaryOS, ubuntu based distro. I installed Neo4j few weeks ago. Now, I started neo4j by executing: ./bin/neo4j console from Neo4j home directory. And the problem is, that there is no graph I created few weeks ago. What could be the problem, that it did not save the graph ?

Another problem: when I execute 
  sudo ./bin/neo4j-installer install 
It says, it is already installed. 
But if I execute: sudo service neo4j-service status or start/stop nothing happens.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can explain how you created the graph back then.

Check which directory Neo4j uses for its database. 
Make sure to find all the graph.db directories that might have accidentally created. 
You can use `locate messages.log` to find them.

Then check `messages.log` or `neo4j.log` and the other log-fiels in the `data/log` directory. They might tell you more about what's wrong.